# Visual Basic Open URL with Default Browser

Tags: url, vb6, browser

**Edit**

For VB 6

**End Edit**

Hey this seems like it should be an easy fix and I don't particularly like the Visual Basic language, but how would I open a URL in the default web browser, using code?

**Edit**
Why do I keep getting this error?

> A call to PInvoke function 'CrackleMail!WindowsApplication1.FormFinal::ShellExecute' has 
>   unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the 
>   unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke 
>   signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: I updated my post to correct the function signature

Comment: Looks like op used the vb6 portion of the accepted answer. Updating the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VB.NET:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://example.com")
```

VB 6 (not sure):

```
Declare Function ShellExecuteA Lib "shell32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Integer) As IntPtr

ShellExecuteA(Me.Handle, "open", "http://example.com", "", "", 4)
```

Comment: I think you don't have to use the Alias.

Comment: @Shimmy: Everything I knew in VB5/6 surely I forgot, so feel free to edit my answer or post your own :)

Comment: In fact, I never knew VB6, but in VB.NET, AFAIK, when you use `Declare` you don't need the `Alias` under this circumstances.

Comment: thanks change ShellExecute(Me.Handle... to ShellExecuteA(Me.Handle

Comment: The declare above gives a compile error 'user-defined type not defined'. I've posted code from MSDN in another answer that works ok

Comment: Call ShellExecuteA(Me.Handle, "open", txtURL.Text, "", "", 4)

Answer (score 15):

The code in the accepted answer gave a compile error for me
I got the code below from MSDN [Use ShellExecute to launch the default Web browser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816)

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                            Lib "shell32.dll" _
                            Alias "ShellExecuteA"( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                            ByVal lpFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
                            As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim r As Long
   r = ShellExecute(0, "open", "http://www.microsoft.com", 0, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

It is simple!
Just use the Wscript `createobject` Method

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Option Explicit

'Link the kernel method that allows a process to be open/spawn

Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                            Lib "shell32.dll" _
                            Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                            ByVal lpFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
                            As Long

Private Sub mnuAbrirNavegador_Click(Index As Integer)
    OpenUrl("http://www.microsoft.com")
End Sub

Private Sub OpenUrl(ByVal url As String)
    r = ShellExecute(0, "open", url, 0, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: worked, just i changed removed brackets from `ShellExecute(0, "open", url, 0, 0, 1)`