# Different results from Shell command on two Windows 10 computers

Tags: shell, vb6

```
FP = "htttp://www.mywebsite.com/anappinstaller.exe"

Shell "iexplore.exe " & FP
```

On one computer it opens a browser to download the file while on the other computer...nothing (as though the code never ran).  Both running Windows 10 Home ,both 64 bit and only one user on each machine.

Using VB6 sp6.  Everything else in the app runs fine on both computers.
Within the IDE, it works flawlessly, so I can't trap it.  I left out the Do while timer code and just showed the relevant snippet.

Is this a permissions issue, anti-virus (one has AVG the other McAfee), windows defender?  Really scratching my head on this one.

Comment: I'd next test it with a different URL, then perhaps a different browser, then perhaps with a different command completely.  If you're saying it works on the same machine in your IDE but not compiled, then it sounds like a permissions problem to me, though.

Comment: I would switch to `ShellExecute` E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16013208/246342 - This will use the users default browser so will work if IE is disabled & it will also return an error code if there is a problem.

Comment: Do both have the same IE version?

Comment: Yes, everyone is on the same version of IE.  Just to be clear, the code above runs smoothly on my development computer within the SDK of VB6 and outside of the SDK as a compiled program.  It is just on other people's Windows 10.  They all appear to be laptops if that matters.